# Transformation using either spark-sql or pyspark pattern matching between columns

Tags: azure, t-sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a problem statement all the column type is string

[image]

Column A pattern if it matches in column C then update Good Stuff with 1 ,else (-)

Any Query in pyspark, sparksql

Thanks
Anuj Gupta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, this should work for you:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when

df.withColumn('Good Stuff', when(col('RouteTypeRankFinal').startsWith(col('Text(RouteRank)')), lit(1)).otherwise(lit('-')))
```

Comment: Hello Robert I try to exec , it is showing invalid syntax.

Comment: Edited it. Forgot quotemarks.

Comment: I tried already this one again error. 
NameError: name 'when' is not defined

Comment: Then you need to import it. Edited my solution

Comment: Seems to be working now.

Comment: An upvote and accept would be appreciated then.

Comment: Definitely. Thankyou.